# Trying to add position fix for div

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I have two divs  `claims-side-panel` and   `alert-section`. I need to add `position:fixed` for `claims-side-panel` so that it can move with scroll. But if I add `position:fixed` then it disturbs the alignment of other div please check my below code

HTML

```
        <div class="row">
          <aside class="col-lg-4 mt-5">
            <div class="claims-side-panel">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="claim-list-item">
                    <span class="fa" [ngClass]="{'image-icon': !claim.category.value }"
                      aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </div>
                </li>

                </ng-container>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="alert-section">
              <assisted-moment [assistData]="assistedMoment" sectionName="OtherRequirements"></assisted-moment>
            </div>
          </aside>

      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div.claims-main-wrapper {
  .fa-spinner {
    @include font-size(40px);
    position: absolute;
    margin: 60px auto; 

    left: 50%;
  }
  aside {
    .claims-side-panel {
      position: fixed; // here I am trying

      ul {
        padding-left: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        li {
          .claim-list-item {
            padding: 14px 28px;
            background-color: $main-background-color;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
            line-height: 26px;
            span {
              &.label {
                @include font-size(16px);
                @include font-style($tertiaryFontFamily, 700);
                color: $text-color;
              }

            p {
              @include font-size(16px);
              font-family: $primaryFontFamily;
              color: $text-color5;
              margin: -4px 0 0 28px;
              word-break: break-word;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  div.alert-section {
    //padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    .table thead th {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color;
    }
    .table th, .table td {
      border-top: 0;
    }

  }
```

[image: Error Image]
Actual Image
[image]

Comment: PLease can you create a [mcve] with the rendered html

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent container aside `position:relative`

```
aside{
position:relative
}
```

Comment: why its width get disturbed when I add position fixed to other div too. Like I pasted the image, if you see, the width of image reduced

Comment: Fixed position usually wrap the elements around the content the width assume the width of the content text plus any padding or margin. you can use position property of left and right to adjust the width

Comment: position property of left? I fixed that by giving width but its not responsive

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed disturbs the whole css because of its own property as fixed so I need to give so I needed to give width and margin which solved my problem